# does ios always stretch just the parent view?

Tags: ios, xib, nib

when I set the size of the view at simulated metrics to iphone 3.5 inch and run the application on iphone 5s , I expect to cut the view. but I see that the ios stretch the panrent view, but doesn't stretch the child views.

does ios always stretch just the parent view ?

so for example:
I have two views:

```
view -
      view
```

so if I set the first view to 3.5 inch with background red, and the second view to 3.5 inch and background yellow and run the app on iphone 5s, then 3.5 inch will be yellow and the rest red

Comment: You can tell it how the inner views are to be resized with their parents.  Exactly how depends on whether or not you have autolayout turned on.

Comment: you are referring to autoresizing, right ?

Comment: Yes, the older way is to set up "springs & struts" to control it and the newer way is to turn on autolayout and set constraints between UI elements.